# Writing a long text into a TextView without blocking the UI thread

Tags: java, android

I haven't found any solution on the web yet, so I asked this here. I have created a simple text file viewer in Android. Since reading the files can be a very time-consuming task, it reads the file in a different thread and then writes the contents into a TextView on the UI thread. Here is my code:

```java
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText path;
    TextView contents;
    String file_path;
    ProgressBar pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        path = findViewById(R.id.path);
        contents = findViewById(R.id.contents);
        pb=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        contents.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission was granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission was denied\nApplication cannot work\nPlease enable permission in settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void display(View view) {
        checkPermission();
        file_path=path.getText().toString();
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        contents.setText("");
        contents.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        Thread t=new Thread(new Reader());
        t.start();
    }

    class Reader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                File f=new File(file_path);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String line;
                final StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); //removing the final newline
                contents.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contents.setText(sb.toString());
                    }
                });
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                contents.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contents.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        contents.setText(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
            pb.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It can display small files very easily, but if the file contents are too large, the UI gets halted for some time and ANR (App Not Responding) message is shown.
This happens not only for files, but also while writing a very long passage into a TextView. What can I do to avoid this? What is the best practice to handle such a situation? A solution not involving support libraries is appreciated. Please ask if any more information is needed.

Comment: What about using a webview to render the text in it?

Comment: Is it a good practice to do so?

Comment: yes, it is if it meets all your requirements like UI & UX.

Comment: Yes, it works, but wouldn't it be a heavier option than TextView?

Comment: yes, it's bit heavier than the textview. You can try to break the text into multiple textviews.

Comment: What do you mean? How to break into multiple textviews?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209308/discussion-between-minhazur-and-puspam).